# gnuplot/pngcairo not rendering UTF-8 character correctly

Tags: unicode, utf-8, gnuplot

I have two CentOS 7.4.1708 machines, running gnuplot 4.6 patchlevel 2,
 currently behaving differently, and I can't work out why.

Install fonts:

```
sudo yum install dejavu-sans-mono-fonts
```

Then create the following GNUplot script:

```
cat << EOF > test.gnuplot
set terminal pngcairo enhanced font "DejaVuSansMono,10"
set encoding utf8
set title "同"
plot sin(x)
EOF
```

Finally, pipe it into the application:

```
cat test.gnuplot | gnuplot > test.png
```

On one machine I get this:

[image: Working as expected]

But on another I get this:

[image: Not working as expected]

I can't work out the cause of the discrepancy. The desired character *is* U+540C so it's not like the second machine is interpreting the input bytes any differently; it's just not rendering the glyph.

What differences in system configuration should I be looking for?

More broadly, how can I "fix" the output in the second case? I don't even vastly care if some characters end up getting replaced by placeholders like this (after all, I must recognise that not all fonts implement all glyphs), but those placeholders being rendered at super-size *is* a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This post is rather a collection of observations than a complete answer, but perhaps it might be useful as well (I tried your example on an almost fresh install of CentOS and it does reproduce the second plot in your post):

1. judging from the `charset` table printed by the command

   ```
   fc-match -v DejaVuSansMono
   ```

   it seems that `540C` is indeed not supported. Perhaps the first machine has some additional fonts installed which are used as a fallback for this particular glyph? How would the output of `fc-list` differ?

   Hard to say if it is complete, but the [list](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/540c/fontsupport.htm) of fonts supporting this glyph seems to be rather limited. Nonetheless, for example Google Droid is available via `yum`, so if I do

   ```
   sudo yum install google-droid-sans-fonts google-droid-sans-mono-fonts
   ```

   and rerun the Gnuplot script, the plot renders in an acceptable way.
2. as for the size of the "fallback" box, I first noticed that its size is directly proportional to the specified font size, i.e., it also doubles if one doubles the font size. From `src/wxterminal/gp_cairo.c`, it seems that Gnuplot uses by default an "oversampling" strategy to render the text, i.e., it renders everything in `plot->oversampling_scale` times larger resolution and then scales it back (via the transformation matrix defined in `void gp_cairo_initialize_context(plot_struct*)`).
   For example, when rendering the text, it calls

   ```
   pango_font_description_set_size(desc, \
       (int) (plot->fontsize*PANGO_SCALE*plot->oversampling_scale));
   ```

   However, for some reason, the "fallback" box is not scaled back and thus is `plot->oversampling_scale` times larger than the specified font size. The default value of `plot->oversampling_scale` is set to `GP_CAIRO_SCALE` which is defined to be `20` in `src/wxterminal/gp_cairo.h`.

   I downloaded the source of Gnuplot 4.6.2 and replaced `plot->oversampling = TRUE;` with `plot->oversampling = FALSE;` in `void gp_cairo_initialize_plot(plot_struct*)` in `src/wxterminal/gp_cairo.c`. After recompilation, the "fallback" box is rendered with the same size as the rest of text. Unfortunately, I haven't found a way how to change this behavior directly from Gnuplot.

Comment: Fallback fonts! Good call. I can't tell exactly which font was being used on my first system, but didn't look for very long (because why). Would you conclude that fixing the root cause is something for which we'd just have to wait for a fix (and new release) in Gnuplot proper? I may just have to leave this as a known issue and let my customers' sysadmins be proactive in installing the fonts they need, rather than letting them be lazy and just rely on the fallback boxes not ruining everything :P

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit as I understand it, it seems to me that Gnuplot is an innocent bystander in this, it delegates the rendering to pango and the scaling strategy seems to be legit, but for some reason pango doesn't scale the "fallback boxes" back to proper size...

Comment: So a pango bug?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it seems to be related to [Bug 636348](https://github.com/GNOME/pango/blob/master/NEWS/#L396) - perhaps it has somehow resurfaced...

Comment: Thanks for your findings - I think I'm going to leave this as a known issue referring to said findings